# MSBuild.Community.Tasks issue with vs2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Folks I've a set of services first created in 2012, which - down the years - have seamlessly built with Vs2010, Vs2013 & Vs2015.

When I try to build with Vs2017 I get

The *MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib* task could not be loaded from the assembly 
The assembly lives under the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks` folder, however there is no `MSBuildCommunityTasks` folder under the `\2017\Professional\MSBuild` folder.

Here's the full error

```
C:\working\MySolution\build\Build.proj" (default target) (1) ->
(SetAssemblyVersion target) ->
  C:\working\MySolution\build\Build.proj(100,5): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. 
  Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
  The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

What changed between Vs2015 and Vs2017?
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: The main change is the install path. It is now nested under a VS folder, including an edition folder, except in the case of standalone build tools install. See [MSBuild release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0) for the release notes.

Your issue is likely caused by the targets not being placed in the correct new location. There is an open issue on their git [MSBuild issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1888) for the Azure SDK with some helpful suggestions to try.

Comment: Thanks Siobhan, I'll check it out Monday

Comment: You can copy `MSBuildCommunityTasks` where its looking for it. i.e. copy folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly setting the `MSBuildCommunityTasksPath` property gets past the problem.

I do this at the top of my build.proj file.

(For historic reasons we keep the community build tasks in our repo, which is why it's set to a location under trunk)

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(trunk)\Ref\Build\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

Answer (score 3):

The extensions are most likely installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild'. So I currently set the variable explicitly in my proj as a workaround.

```
<MSBuildExtensionsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing .Net Framework 3.5 development tools in VS2017 individual components section fixed my build.